# CSS round focus class on element

Tags: css

In order to create an onboarding tutorial for a website I'm trying to create a class that when added an element creates a backdrop on the rest and a rounded focus on the element it was added to, something as follow:

[image]

I've tried with the outline properties but the rest is still clickable and I can't get it to cover the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a screenshot from this page.
give it these styles:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);  /* that dark effect in your picture, customize 
                                 it however u like*/
z-index: -1; /* put it behind your main component */
```

Then give your main component this style:

```
clip-path: circle(200px at var(--x) var(--y));
```

Change `200px` to get the circle with the width you want.

`var(--x)` and `var(--y)` are the center of your circle.

Should be able to work it out by `clip-path`.
Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

In short, it cuts only a piece of the element you put this style on.

So the button and area around it(that `clip-path` i set up there is type circle...) will be cut from your component, and all around that circle, is the element you have put behind it.

Comment: so what you're saying is have an image to act as the overlay and cut a circle through it, but that will break the responsiveness no?

Comment: In your case, you have to cut a circle in your main component. And the image behind it will be visible with your cut circle on top of it. As for responsiveness, I didn't think about it. instead of an image, you can call your component twice, but that is kinda messy. Another way is to handle it with `::before ::after`. put these two on your button, one of them be as big as the page, the other should be circle on top of your button. That circle is easy to make. get center with `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.
The first one is the gray overlay.